# Magento 2 - Create admin grid with two tables of different structures using UI Component

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5

Need to create an admin grid on Magento 2 with data of two custom tables of different structures.

FYI, unable to proceed with joins and union.

Can you please anyone provide the best solution to achieve this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions mentioned in [this article](https://webkul.com/blog/create-collection-grid-editadd-grid-row-installer-magento2/) to create the grid.

Now, follow these steps:

1. To join, you have to add the following codes in **di.xml** file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--
       /**
        * Webkul Grid DI
        *
        * @category    Webkul
        * @package     Webkul_Grid
        * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
        *
        */
    -->
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <!-- here we remove virtualType and defile collection as follow-->
       <type name="Webkul\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">wk_grid_records</argument>
               <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">wk_records_grid_collection</argument>
               <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">wk_grid_records_collection</argument>
               <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Webkul\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
           </arguments>
       </type>
       <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                   <!--data provider name which used in grid ui component file -->
                   <item name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">Webkul\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection</item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. Then you have to update **Collection.php** file in **app/code/Webkul/Grid/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php** with the following codes:

   ```
   /**
    * Webkul Grid collection
    *
    * @category    Webkul
    * @package     Webkul_Grid
    * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
    *
    */

    namespace Webkul\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

    /* use required classes */
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

    class Collection extends 
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
    {
    /**
    * @var string
    */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

   /**
    * @param EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    * @param LoggerInterface        $logger,
    * @param FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    * @param ManagerInterface       $eventManager,
    * @param StoreManagerInterface  $storeManager,
    * @param AdapterInterface       $connection,
    * @param AbstractDb             $resource
    */
   public function __construct(
       EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
       LoggerInterface $logger,
       FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
       ManagerInterface $eventManager,
       StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       AdapterInterface $connection = null,
       AbstractDb $resource = null
   ) {
       $this->_init('Webkul\Grid\Model\Grid', 'Webkul\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
       //Class naming structure 
       // 'NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\ModelName', 'NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName'
       parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
       $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
   }

   protected function _initSelect()
   {
       parent::_initSelect();

       $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
           ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('wk_record_temp')], //2nd table name by which you want to join mail table
           'main_table.record_id = secondTable.record_id', // common column which available in both table 
           '*' // '*' define that you want all column of 2nd table. if you want some particular column then you can define as ['column1','column2']
       );
       }

       }
   ```
3. Create **Collection.php** file in
   **app/code/Webkul/Grid/Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Grid**.
4. Now, you can add 2nd table columns in **grid_record_grid_list.xml** in
   **app/code/Webkul/Grid/view/adminhtml/ui_component** folder.

You can find more information about these steps [right here](https://webkul.com/blog/join-two-table-and-create-grid-in-admin-section-using-ui-component-in-magento2/).

Comment: thanks a lot !!!! Working superb !!!!

But how can I add custom query in collection of multiple custom tables?.

Comment: How to get custom collection not from table ?